# Why I am not able to Iterate my first FOR loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I am writing a python code to find all possible  combinations of password with specific rules

1. should contain alphabets A-Z a-z
2. should contain numbers 0-9
3. should contain special symbols
4. first character of password must be capital letter

```py
from itertools import permutations

pw = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]"
firstchar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

c = permutations(pw, 2) #3 is the password length for providing sample output quickly
f=open("password.txt","w+")
f.truncate(0)

for x in firstchar:
    for i in c: 
        current_pw = x + "".join(i)
        f.write( "\t" + current_pw + "\n" )
```

**
the output contains only password starting from A and stops doesn't iterate for B, C...
**

Comment: Note that `itertools.permutations` returns an [_iterator_](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), not a list or other sequence type. Iterators can only be consumed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `permutation` quits after the first loop.
So you define `c` in each loop.

```
from itertools import permutations

pw = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]"
firstchar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

f=open("password.txt","w+")
f.truncate(0)

for x in firstchar:
    c = permutations(pw, 2)          # c is defined here
    for i in c: 
        current_pw = x + "".join(i)
        f.write( "\t" + current_pw + "\n" )
```